# Specifying ON DELETE NO ACTION in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework 7 when I am trying to apply a migration I get the error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ChangeOrder_User_CreatedByID' on table 'ChangeOrder' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I know in older versions of Entity Framework you would deal with this by adding

```cs
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

to the DbContext but in EF7 `modelBuilder` does not seem to have a `.Conventions` to it and google is only returning older EF 4 though EF 6 results.

How do I specific the `ON DELETE NO ACTION` constraint in Entity Framework 7?

Edit:
The answer provided by Oleg will apparently do it per Foreign Key but I would like to do it globally as it will much easier to use one line of code to declare this globally then have to specify code it out for every single one of the hundreds of relationships I will end up having.

Edit 2: Code for Oleg

```cs
public class ChangeOrder
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Int16? ApprovedByID { get; set; }
    public Byte ApprovalStatusID { get; set; }
    public Int16 AssignedToID { get; set; }
    public Int16 CreatedByID { get; set; }
    public Byte CurrentStatusID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public Byte ImpactID { get; set; }
    public Byte PriorityID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public Byte TypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ReasonForChange { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApprovedByID")]
    public User ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApprovalStatusID")]
    public ChangeApprovalStatus ApprovalStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignedToID")]
    public User AssignedTo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByID")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImpactID")]
    public ChangeImpact Impact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriorityID")]
    public ChangePriority Priority { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeID")]
    public ChangeType ChangeType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentStatusID")]
    public ChangeStatus CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class JobSightDBContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);
    }

    DbSet<ChangeApprovalStatus> ChangeApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeImpact> ChangeImapct { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangePriority> ChangePriorities { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeStatus> ChangeStatus { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeType> ChangeTypes { get; set; }
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

After digging around on GitHub, and working with a very patient guy from MS there, the current solution is to add this to the DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
{
    foreach (var relationship in modelbuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    {
        relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);
}
```

Comment: this saved my life!!!!! I was getting lots of modeling FK issues. Thanks a million!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: There is a `DeleteBehavior` but there is no `UpdateBehavior`?

Comment: This doesn't work in EF Core 2.1 :(

Comment: Not working for me: 'DbModelBuilder'  does not contain a definition for 'Model'..

Comment: This worked for me on EF Core 2.0.2.  Just ensure you have your base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder) and the above method prior to your bindings.

Comment: It worked for me on EF Core 2.1 but as mentioned before, `base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);` needs to be at the top

Comment: Just to add a note, if it doesn't see SelectMany (by default) add using System.Linq;

Comment: You are genius . It works magically !!

Comment: great lines. Thank you

Answer (score 18):

The construction

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity("myNamespace.Models.ChangeOrder", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("myNamespace.Models.User")
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("CreatedByID")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    });
```

will means creating `FK_ChangeOrder_User_CreatedByID` with `REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([CreatedByID]) ON DELETE CASCADE`. It should exist in `protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` of `YourContextModelSnapshot.cs` created during migration. I'm not sure that I full understand your question, but I think that you should either add such construct to `XXXModelSnapshot.cs` or to remove unneeded construct, which already exist here.

**UPDATED:** I see that you have the problem in the Model. You have the following properties in

```cs
public Int16? ApprovedByID { get; set; }
public Int16 AssignedToID { get; set; }
public Int16 CreatedByID { get; set; }

// navigation properties

[ForeignKey("ApprovedByID")]
public User ApprovedBy { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AssignedToID")]
public User AssignedTo { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CreatedByID")]
public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

By default migration try to set `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` on all the properties.

You can overwrite the behavior by changing `OnModelCreating`, which sets either `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` behavior for all the keys or to set on one only key the `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` or `DeleteBehavior.SetNull` behavior. For example, the below code uses `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` on `CreatedByID` (which creates `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign keys) and `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` on other foreign keys (no `ON DELETE` on the foreign keys):

```cs
public class JobSightDBContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);

        modelbuilder.Entity(typeof (ChangeOrder))
            .HasOne(typeof (User), "ApprovedBy")
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("ApprovedByID")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // no ON DELETE
        modelbuilder.Entity(typeof (ChangeOrder))
            .HasOne(typeof (User), "AssignedTo")
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("AssignedToID")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // no ON DELETE
        modelbuilder.Entity(typeof (ChangeOrder))
            .HasOne(typeof (User), "CreatedBy")
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("CreatedByID")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // set ON DELETE CASCADE
    }

    DbSet<ChangeApprovalStatus> ChangeApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeImpact> ChangeImapct { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangePriority> ChangePriorities { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeStatus> ChangeStatus { get; set; }
    DbSet<ChangeType> ChangeTypes { get; set; }
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally or do I have to do it for each of the hundreds of relationships I have? Doing it this way will create a lot of extra coding for me and I would rather avoid doing that.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: It's difficult to answer having only the error message. I suppose that you created first a set of classes which have many data notations and then created `XXXContext` derived from `DbContext` which have many properties like `public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }`, `public DbSet<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }`. I suppose that some definitions in `User`, `ChangeOrder` will be interpreted in a wrong way by EF Migration, but I can't guess what exactly it could be. One nee to analyse full Model to find the reason.

Comment: Not sure what your having problems understanding. I am looking for the EF7 version of `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();` but I have added the DBContext and a model for you to look at

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: I want just to inform you shortly that I have to do now some important things for my customer. I'll came back to your problem later (in some hours).

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: I updated my answer. See `OnModelCreating` in **UPDATED** part.

Comment: Yes, that will do it per property but as stated I want to do it globally. I will end up having hundreds of properties that need this applied to and don't want to do ever single one individually, leaves to much room for error.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: I'm not understand what you want to say. You can see that EF7 try to set by default `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Thus you have to inform EF7 on which one such fields you really need to set `ON DELETE CASCADE` and on which NO ACTION. I've shown you **how** you can gives EF7 the required information. You should decide yourself how to implement this in your environment.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: For example you can extend `ChangeOrder` with ` public static void SetOnDelete(ModelBuilder modelbuilder) {...}` which do the changes from `OnModelCreating` and to call `ChangeOrder.SetOnDelete(modelbuilder);` in `OnModelCreating`. In the way you can easy extend `JobSightDBContext`.

Comment: @Olga Yes, EF7 default behavior is to set `ON DELETE CASCADE` I want to override this and remove that behavior so the default becomes `ON DELTE NO ACTION`. In EF6 this was done with `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();`. What you have shown me is how to do one by one for each property. What I need to know is how to set `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` as the default behavior for EF7.