# Entity framework 7 in ASP.NET MVC6 multiple foreign key to the same table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Hi I have the same problem that an old post that is here, the solution offer there doesn't work for me in MVC 6 with EF7 is simple

```
public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int MatchId { get; set; }

    public DateTime playday { get; set; }
    public float HomePoints { get; set; }
    public float GuestPoints { get; set; }

    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int GuestTeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeTeamId")]
    [InverseProperty("HomeMatches")]
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GuestTeamId")]
    [InverseProperty("AwayMatches")]
    public virtual Team GuestTeam { get; set; }

}

public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; }
}
```

this is the best way that I found, because I can add a new migration and all is ok, but when I update the database I get an error like this

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Match_Team_HomeTeamId' on table 'Match' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: it would be important if you append your question with the definition of the context class (inherited from `DbContext`) , where `Match` and `Team` be used. One can make some changes in the context class to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I analysed the problem in details during preparing [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34769623/315935) and I can suggest you two solutions of the problem.

The problem exist because of two properties in the class `Match`

```cs
public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
public int GuestTeamId { get; set; }
```

and the foreign keys `HomeTeamId` and `GuestTeamId` which will be generated. EF7 generate the foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which can't be used for more as one foreign key. The current implementation of Entity Framework (RC1) have no annotation attribute, which you can use to change the behavior.

The first solution of the problem would be to use nullable properties like

```cs
public int? HomeTeamId { get; set; }
public int? GuestTeamId { get; set; }
```

or

```cs
public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
public int? GuestTeamId { get; set; }
```

Maximum one property should be non nullable. As the result the problem will be solved, but one will have small disadvantage, which could be not important for some scenarios. The field in the database table for nullable property will have no `NOT NULL` property in the column definition.

If you do need to hold both `HomeTeamId` and `GuestTeamId` non-nullable then you can solve the problem by modifying the context class (inherited from DbContext), where the classes `Match` and `Team` be used.

You have already some context class defined line below

```cs
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    DbSet<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

To solve the describe problem you can add protected `OnModelCreating` in the class which explicitly set

```cs
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);

        modelbuilder.Entity(typeof (Match))
            .HasOne(typeof (Team), "GuestTeam")
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("GuestTeamId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // no ON DELETE

        modelbuilder.Entity(typeof (Match))
            .HasOne(typeof (Team), "HomeTeam")
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("GuestTeamId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // set ON DELETE CASCADE
    }

    DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    DbSet<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

You can use of cause `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` on both foreign keys (instead of usage of `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` on one). It's important to remark that the last approach allows to hold both `HomeTeamId` and `GuestTeamId`, like the corresponding fields in the database, as non-nullable.

See [the documentation](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#id18) for additional information.

Comment: What you say help me a lot because I can understand better the problem but still not working for me, the nullable int don't work, for me, I still have the same error when I run the dnx ef database update command
and the second way looks like the best way but then I get this error when I run the update
The navigation 'GuestTeam' on entity type 'WebApplication1.Models.Match' has not been added to the model, or ignored, or target entityType ignored.

Comment: @DennisGonzalez: I'm sure that you made small errors in both cases. You can provide the full demo project somewhere (on GitHub for example, which available for free). If I can reproduce the problem I can quickly find the reason and fix it. By the way, it seems to me that you use `InverseProperty` attribute in the wrong way. Try to remove it.

Comment: as soon as i can i will, i have this project on github but i have not commit and pull all the changes because i try all the possible solutions that i found on internet and nothing works so when i get home i will upload a new project with all that you say, if yoy prefer this is a previos version on github that does'nt have what you told me https://github.com/Crash1988/SmartMove/tree/master/SmartMove

Comment: @DennisGonzalez: Typically `git push origin` should work. If you work under Windows then [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) is the most simple way to support GitHub repository. I use it permanently. More advance, but a little more compel to use client which I can recommend is [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). It seems that the code on SmartMove from your repository is not up-to-date. I see that you use in the code "Individual User Account". Is it required? I'd recommend to use "No Authentication" at the beginning or "Windows Authentication".

Comment: @DennisGonzalez: Try [the project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/SmartMove.zip), where I removed many not required parts. You can build the project then start command prompt in the project directory and execute `dnx ef migrations add Initial` (or `dnx ef migrations add Initial -v -c MyDBContext`) which creates migrations. After that you can build the project with created Migrations and execute `dnx ef database update -v`. After that you can work with the project. It seems your problem was because you tried to use Individual User Account database for your custom data.

Comment: Thanks you So much, now its running!!, just start another new project and only add those 2 models first and is working, now I will start adding the other models and see if there was the problem, if you like to see it this is the GitHub address https://github.com/Crash1988/MVC.git

Comment: @DennisGonzalez: Yes, you can do this in the way. It's design question, whether to use *one* DB context for the information about users and roles mixed with other data or to use two separate databases and two contexts (`MyDBContext` derived from `DbContext` **and** `ApplicationDbContext` derived from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`). I personally prefer to separate the information. Another small tip: it's better to hold the standard C# name conversion and to use `Playday` or `PlayDay` property instead of `playday` (see `Match`), `string Name` instead of `String name` in `Team` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer you can create on database manually this FK with cascade delete, and check why you are havign this circular cascade loop. To understand that we need the other tables or the database structure involved. Please inspect your database (with a diagram for example), draw down your connected tables, your FKs and for each study the operation you planned (cascade delete, no action, ...) and the direction of them. You fill find a loop when you will try to insert that FK in error.

The next phase is to understand if you want it or not, is an unwanted database design? Or simply you don't need this FK action? In this case you can suppress it in various levels: on model, on settings, ... se the other post or the EF guide for that.