# EF7 Foreign Keys , cascade and restrict

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Trying to learn how to model relationships in EF7 and how to use Foreign Keys,Those are the models that I made up simplified

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        //..
        public virtual List<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

public class BlogPost
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BlogPostId { get; set; }
        //...

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    }

  public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CommentId { get; set; }
        //..

        public int BlogPostId { get; set; }
        public virtual BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

- `User` has `One to Many` Relationship with `Comments`
- `User` has `One to Many` Relationship with `BlogPosts`
- `BlogPost` has `One to One` Relationship with `User`
- `BlogPost` has `One to Many` Relationship with `Comment`
- `Comment` has `One to One` Relationship with `User`
- `Comment` has `One to One` Relationship with `BlogPost`
- When I delete a `User` all of his `Comments` and `BlogPosts` should be
  deleted using the releveant FK
- When I delete a `BlogPost` all of its `Comments` should be deleted using the relevant FK

So I translated the above into this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().
                HasOne(p => p.User).
                WithMany(p => p.Comments).
                OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict). 
                HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().
                HasOne(p => p.BlogPost).
                WithMany(p => p.Comments).
                OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict).
                HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogPostId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
                HasMany(p => p.Comments).
                WithOne(p => p.User).
                OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade).
                HasForeignKey(p => p.CommentId);


            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
                HasMany(p => p.BlogPosts).
                WithOne(p => p.User).
                OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade).
                HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogPostId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().
                HasOne(p => p.User).
                WithMany(p => p.BlogPosts).
                HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId).
                OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().
                HasMany(p => p.Comments).
                WithOne(p => p.BlogPost).
                OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade).
                HasForeignKey(p => p.CommentId);

        }
```

But this looks like too much typing, and I can't find good docs yet on Entity Framework 7. My question is, am I doing anything unnecessary given the points I mentioned above, can I type less and still get what I mentioned?

Comment: I think you mean BlogPost has a one to many relationship to Comment

Comment: I think that if you use [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) and a [DBContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) you could skip the whole `OnModelCreating` method code block

Comment: @Prescott but how can i specify the OnDelete behavior in annotations? couldn't find a way to do that with annotations, i think its cascade by default, not sure

Comment: Well, ok, you need some stuff in `OnModelCreating`, but you could simplify a bunch by only specifying the OnDelete if it's different than default

Comment: @Prescott: I think that one really need to define new data annotation attribute which allows to specify OnDelete behavior, something like `[OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)]`. Currently there are exist no such attribute. See [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35101573/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34769623/315935). One have to use `OnModelCreating`, but one want to have declarative way in some scenarios.

Comment: Thank you both that was helpful