# Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>() in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my regular .NET Framework application, I was using EF 6.x and was also using some Inheritance, specifically:

> **PurchaseOrder.cs** and **SaleOrder.cs** both inherit from **Order.cs**

And in the `OnModelCreating()` on my context class inheriting from `IdentityDbContext`, I was doing:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

This used to work, but now I am moving my application to .NET Core 2.0 and I am using EF Core. What achieves the same thing in EF Core? Because right now I am getting the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Order_Business_CustomerId' on table 'Order' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code after Ahmar's answer. In my context class, I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  builder.HasDefaultSchema("PD");

  builder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(c => c.SaleOrders)
    .WithOne(e => e.Customer)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

  builder.Entity<Supplier>()
    .HasMany(po => po.PurchaseOrders)
    .WithOne(e => e.Supplier)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

  builder.Entity<PurchaseOrder>()
    .HasMany(li => li.LineItems)
    .WithOne(po => po.PurchaseOrder)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

  builder.Entity<SaleOrder>()
    .HasMany(li => li.LineItems)
    .WithOne(po => po.SaleOrder)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```

And as far the Entities, they are:

```
public abstract class Business : IEntity
{
  protected Business()
  {
    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
  public string Website { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
  public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
}

[Table("Customers")]
public class Customer : Business
{
  public decimal AllowedCredit { get; set; }
  public decimal CreditUsed { get; set; }
  public int NumberOfDaysAllowedToBeOnMaxedOutCredit { get; set; }
  public ICollection<SaleOrder> SaleOrders { get; set; }
}

[Table("Suppliers")]
public class Supplier : Business
{
  public ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Order : IEntity
{
  protected Order()
  {
    Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public decimal ShippingCost { get; set; }
  public Currency ShippingCurrency { get; set; }
  public decimal ShippingConversionRate { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

[Table("PurchaseOrders")]
public class PurchaseOrder : Order
{
  public int SupplierOrderNumber { get; set; }
  public PurchaseOrderStatus Status { get; set; }
  public decimal Vat { get; set; }
  public decimal ImportDuty { get; set; }
  public int SupplierId { get; set; }
  public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
  public ICollection<PurchaseOrderLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

[Table("SaleOrders")]
public class SaleOrder : Order
{
  public decimal AmountToBePaidOnCredit { get; set; }
  public SaleOrderStatus Status { get; set; }
  public ICollection<SaleOrderLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

So after doing what Ahmar suggested, I still get the same error when I do `update-database`.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768976/specifying-on-delete-no-action-in-entity-framework-7

Answer (score 2):

For newer EF you need to change the method, here is the correct example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (modelBuilder == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");

    // for the other conventions, we do a metadata model loop
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        entityType.SetTableName(entityType.DisplayName());

        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        entityType.GetForeignKeys()
            .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(fk => fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Solution by Dennes Torres, source: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/change-delete-behavior-and-more-on-ef-core/

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure cascade delete behavior on each entity in .Net Core EF.

The Entity Framework Core Fluent API `OnDelete` method is used to specify the action which should take place on a dependent entity in a relationship when the principal is deleted.

The [OnDelete](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method) method takes a `DeleteBehavior` enum as a parameter:

- Cascade - dependents should be deleted
- Restrict - dependents are
  unaffected
- SetNull - the foreign key values in dependent rows should
  update to NULL

Example:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(Modelbuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Employees)
        .WithOne(e => e.Company).
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```

When deleting the Company, it will set CompanyId property in Employee table to null.

Get more detail at [Configuring One To Many Relationships](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration)

**PS.** Please make sure your all referencing properties should be null able so, EF Core can set them null on delete. like `CompanyId` in about example.

Comment: Sorry @Ahmar, it compiled it, but when I run `Update-Database` it still gives me the same error. Here are [the classes](https://hastebin.com/hoxagefage.cs).

Comment: strange, sorry I updated the question to add the code.

Comment: @Ciwan You need to make SupplierId and CustomerId nullable in SaleOrder and PurchaseOrder entities. I also update my answer as well.

Comment: Still didn't work, even after I made them `nullable`. I got the same error :/

Comment: Did you create new migration after making them `nullable` ?
Remove old migrations and add new then try to do `update-database`

Comment: I try this in a project on my machine with your code and it works.